# How to add JOGL javadoc path to Eclipse using Gradle?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, jogl

I'm using JOGL in Eclipse with Gradle, but the standard way of adding a JavaDoc path in Eclipse, where you edit the "Properties / Java Build Path / Libraries / [jar in question]", the "edit" option is grayed out because the "jogl-all-2.0.jar" file is listed as a "persisted" Gradle dependency and is "non-modifiable".

I presume one has to edit the "build.gradle" file where the JOGL dependency is listed. But I can't figure out what needs to be added to get the Javadoc references to show up. Any ideas?

Here's my current "build.gradle" file:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
       downloadJavaDoc=true
    }
}
subprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs libDirectory, loadDirectory
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile name: 'jogl-all', version: '2.0-rc11'
        compile name: 'gluegen-rt', version: '2.0-rc11'
        compile name: 'jocl'
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't go on using the RC11 which is very old... Please rather use the version 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Well this may not be the best way to do it, but I solved the issue by commenting out the JOGL dependency in the "build.gradle" file, deleted all my projects in Eclipse, then recreated them using the Gradle "Build Model" option. After doing that, the projects have errors because they can't find JOGL, so I edited the properties of the projects and manually added a reference to the JOGL JAR file. Once I did that, then finally Eclipse would allow me to edit the JavaDoc setting for the JOGL JAR.

What a pain.

Comment: You should contact our contributors on the IRC channel, some use Gradle, maybe they have a better solution for your problem: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=jogamp